# Why does query with AND and OR operators yield unexpected results?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have this query but it's not giving me the expected results:
`User.all(:conditions => ["company_id == ? AND role_id == ? OR role_id == ? OR role_id == ?", X, 1,2,3 ])`

It's supposed to mean: Get all the users with X company_id AND their roles can be either 1 or 2 or 3.

So it can be either of those roles, but ALL of those users have to be from THAT company_id.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It isn't working because the precedence is wrong. That is,

```
company_id = ? AND role_id = ? OR role_id = ? OR role_id = ?
```

is interpreted as

```
((company_id = ? AND role_id = ?) OR role_id = ?) OR role_id = ?
```

because AND has higher precedence than OR -- but more relevant to this case -- they are also both are leftward-associative.

The simple fix would thus be:

```
company_id = ? AND (role_id = ? OR role_id = ? OR role_id = ?)
```

(But see other answers for an alternative syntax and/or approaches. I also took the liberty of fixing the equality operator.)

Happy coding.

Answer (score 3):

Could be a couple things.

First use single equals `=`, not double equals `==` in `:conditions => "..."`.

Second, you could either use `"...AND role_id IN (?,?,?)", X, 1, 2, 3])`, or you need to group your `role_id` comparisons with parenthesis so it would be `condition AND (condition OR condition OR condition)`.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to investigate https://github.com/binarylogic/searchlogic

However otherwise you could say

```
User.all(:conditions => ["company_id = ? AND role_id IN (?,?,?)", X, 1,2,3 ])
```

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, this helped me a lot ease up this kind of finds, you could do:

```
company_id = "X"
role_ids = [1,2,3]
User.find(:all, :conditions => "company_id=#{company_id} AND role_id IN (#{role_ids.join(',')})")
```